# Cron jobs to generate html pages? Or better to have user run php script?

Tags: php, html, performance, web, cron

I'm fairly new to web development and had a question regarding page generation and efficiency. I am aware of how to create cron jobs, and was wondering what is considered better, should I run a cron job (say every hour) to build a new set of html pages based on information in my database, or should all the links on my page be to the php script that generates the html page? For some applications I can understand why the page must be created whenever the user requests it - since content will change frequently, however this is just a personal portfolio type website which will have pretty sparse and small updates in terms of new entries in the database. Right now I'm just linking to the php scripts, but it seems like useless recomputing since 95% of the time nothing will have changed, and is not really time sensitive (i could always add an automatic push when I update content anyway - in which case it wouldn't even need cron jobs). BTW, I did build a protected administrator page into the site so I can update content without having to go into the code all the time. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating the HTML with a cronjob would be overly complex. You can just use a caching system like Varnish. Varnish would do all the heavy lifting for you.

It works like this:
- user 1 go's to your webpage
- Varnish handles the request, it's the first request to the page so Varnish will tell Apache/PHP to generate the page
- user 1 gets your webpage
- Varnish stores this webpage into it's cache (as html)
- user 2 visits the webpage
- Varnish has the page in its cache and it will send it to the user (very quick this time as the page doesn't need to be generated again)

Benefits are that you don't have to maintain your cronjobs and that you can just keep your old URL's.

Ofcourse Varnish is just one of many possible caching solutions.

Comment: Thanks! I guess most web hosting services already have something like this built into their servers. I was concerned that maybe I had to implement it myself.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a custom caching problem. Why not just use something like APC to cache rather than make your own? Clear the APC cache on any new entries, and it's done.

Comment: ahh, so does the server do what I am wondering about automatically? Does it cache pages so that it does not need to re-run the php script when the user returns unless content will have changed? How does it know? Any good resources on this?